# Qt QString to QByteArray and back

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qbytearray

I have a problem with tranformation from QString to QByteArray and then back to QString:

```
int main() {

    QString s;

    for(int i = 0; i < 65536; i++) {
        s.append(QChar(i));
    }

    QByteArray ba = s.toUtf8();

    QString s1 = QString::fromUtf8(ba);

    if(areSame(s, s1)) {
        qDebug() << "OK";
    } else {
       qDebug() << "FAIL";
       outputErrors(s, s1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I fill QString with all characters that are within 16bit range. and then convert them to QByteArray (Utf8) and back to QString. The problem is that the character with value 0 and characters with value larger than 55295 fail to convert back to QString.

If I stay within range 1 to < 55297 this test passes.

Comment: The 0 character terminates a string, so it's obvious that it won't work

Comment: Forgot about '\0' but still I don't understand problem with other values.

Comment: Maybe these unicode characters are not implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters from 55296 (0xD800) up to 57343 (0xdfff) are [surrogate characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates).
You can see it as an escape character for the character after it. They have no meaning in itself.

You can check it by running:

```
// QChar(0) was omitted so s and s1 start with QChar(1)
for (int i = 1 ; i < 65536 ; i++)
{
    qDebug() << i << QChar(i) << s[i-1]  << s1[i-1] << (s[i-1] == s1[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the strings still be equal?

Comment: When calling QString::toUtf8() codepoints U+D800 to U+DFFF are replaced by 0x3F which is '?'. That's where the information is lost.

Comment: They're not "escape characters" -- the combined value of a surrogate, with the one after it, encodes a code point. If you have a disjoined sequence of surrogates then your encoding is broken, and Qt is allowed to do anything with it. Including replacing stray surrogates with a `'?'`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a task to convert `std::string` to `QString`, and `QString` to `QByteArray`. Following is what I did in order to complete this task.

```
std::string str = "hello world";

QString qstring = QString::fromStdString(str);

QByteArray buffer;
```

If you look up the documentation for "`QByteArray::append`", it takes `QString` and returns `QByteArray`.

```
buffer = buffer.append(str);
```